# can the graph edges be objects?

Tags: python, oop, graph, networkx

I am a beginner in python, so apologize in advance if my question is simple!
I want to create a graph and use NetworkX for this purpose. the nodes are objects.

but edges have many dynamic attributes too. can the edges be objects? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [networkX documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) this is how you add attributes to edges:

[image: NetworkX Doc]

Take special care when naming a 'weight' attribute since it will be used as the weight in weighted graphs, as you can read above.

Regarding your question *"Can edges be objects?"* - You can create an object (class) that contains information that you will later use in an edge.

For example:

```
class Edge:
      def __init__(self, weight, someAttribute):
          self.weight = weights
          self.attribute = someAttribute
      def otherFunction(self):
          # Do/Store something
          return 0;
```

You can create instances of this class to later use them to create your edges with the syntax provided by netrworkX.

Same goes with nodes, in fact you can create objects of almost anything, that is the point of OOP.

Answer (score -1):

Also a beginner but I've been looking at the documentation available at

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html

Where it says: 
Add edge attributes using add_edge(), add_edges_from(), subscript notation, or G.edge.

```
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7 )
>>> G.add_edges_from([(3,4),(4,5)], color='red')
>>> G.add_edges_from([(1,2,{'color':'blue'}), (2,3,{'weight':8})])
>>> G[1][2]['weight'] = 4.7
>>> G.edge[1][2]['weight'] = 4
```

So it looks like it has a dictionary of key value pairs associated with edges which will hopefully serve your purpose.

Comment: I saw this documentation before, but think maybe this is not very efficient in my program... and thank U :)